# PHP - Ошибка в маршрутизаторе MVC

Tags: php

Пишу свой маршрутизатор для MVC-приложения. Когда маршрут совпадает с названием какой-либо директории, выводится ее содержимое. К примеру, маршрут `site.ru/controllers`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Router:

```
class Router
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT_PATH . '/config/routes.php';

        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach($this->routes as $pattern => $path) {
            if (preg_match("~$pattern~", $uri)) {

                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$pattern~", $path, $uri);

                $segment = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = ucfirst(array_shift($segment)) . 'Controller';
                $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segment));

                $controllerFile = ROOT_PATH . '/controllers/' . $controllerName . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                $controllerObject = new $controllerName();

                if (is_callable(array($controllerObject, $actionName))) {
                    $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $segment);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Конфиг routes.php:

```
<?php

return array(
    '' => 'index/index'
);
```

Конфиг .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Пробовал добавлять в `routes.php` названия директорий, но это не решило проблему - все равно выводилась директория по соответствующему маршруту. Как решить эту проблему?

Добавление этих опций решает проблему, но мне кажется, маршрутами должен заниматься маршрутизатор, а не сам Apache:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

Comment: Правильнее спрятать весь движок выше корня сайта. Доступными оставить только статику (картинки, стили и т.п.). Или `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` закоментируйте.

Comment: @Visman каким образом можно спрятать движок? Последнее помогло, спасибо, но заинтересовала ваша мысль.

Comment: Вот для примера структура laravel https://github.com/laravel/laravel DocumentRoot (в настройках apache) указывает на папку public, в которой лежат .htaccess, index.php, robots.txt, favicon.ico и css с js. И только эта папка доступна извне.

Comment: фреймоврк yii 1.x - вся структура в корне веб сервера, .htaccess файлы запрещают просмотры папок, а все запросы перенаправляются на index.php. Версия yii 2.x - только папка web лежит в корне веб сервера, остальные вне, и к ним не получишь доступ, .htaccess - добавляют если нужны красивые url, а так в целом, можно этого и не делать, в данной папке только index.php и файлы css/js (обычно)